# $.ajax({url:link}) and Jquery UI Droppable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a problem.
I drop element into `#projectsActive`. New element have been created there. Old element have been deleted with `fadeOut`

But ajax query sometimes isn't running.

What's the reason?

```
$("#projectsActive").droppable({
    drop: function (event, elem)
    {
        var e = elem.draggable;
        var linkToSend = "/Projects/Publish/" + $(e).attr("projectid");

        $.ajax({ url: linkToSend });
        var projectid = $(e).attr("projectid");
        var innerText = "";
        if ($(e).find("a").length > 0)
        {
            innerText = $(e).children("a").html();
        }
        else
        {
            innerText = $(e).html();
        }
        var newObject = '<li class="project dragg" projectid="' + projectid + '"><a href="/Projects/' + projectid + '">' + innerText + '</a></li>';



        $(e).fadeOut("fast", function ()
        {
            $("#projectsActive").append(newObject);
            $(this).remove();

            BindDrags();

        });

    }
});
```

Comment: `fadeOut` doesn't delete (remove from DOM) an element, it simply makes that element transparent.

Comment: @Peter: He is calling `remove()` on the `fadeOut()` callback. As for the question, I've looked through it and could find no error. Maybe more information (such as where exactly does it fail, or more code) would help.

Comment: It's a very strange bug.
This code is normally works 3-5 times. But after ajax request doesn't work.I've checked DOM tree in order to check properly deleting.
I can't find any hint to solve this problem

Comment: Track your `linkToSend` variable. Try `console.log(linkToSend)`;

Comment: I've got the same problem on checkbox. It can be help
$("input.ajax-checkbox").change(
function ()
{
    var action = $(this).attr("action");
    var userId = $(this).attr("userid");
    var link = "/Admin/User" + action + "/" + userId;
    $.ajax({ url: link });
});
First time click on checkbox - ajax is working. Next times it won't work.

May be problem is in ASP.NET Server.

Comment: @user418251 - Is this happening in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: Try moving   $("#projectsActive").append(newObject); out of  $(e).fadeOut.